# Ruby on Rails deployment on Amazon ElasticBeanstalk:Signature Expired Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This is the first time I am deploying my application to Amazon EC2 using Beanstalk .
I am following this guide.
Click (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html)

After filling all the info after eb init.

At the step

**Select a solution stack.**

It is throwing me the same error everytime

$ SignatureDoesNotMatch. Signature expired: 20141211T092422Z is now earlier than 20141212T091944Z (20141212T092444Z - 5 min.)

I am entering the access key and secret as provided by Amazon security credentials.

How can I deploy my application? Any tutorials/articles where I can find some other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,It was happening because of server clock and my local machine time was not synchronized.

It can be done by installing ntp tools on your machine.

Article followed 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-ntp-to-synchronize-server-clock/